# How to extract comma separated column values from database using php

Tags: php, mysql

In my database table there is a column named 'marks' . it contains values like 50,55,67,88,...
Now I need to read this values one by one like - first 50, then 55 and so on. How is it possible using php ?

```
include("db_connect.php"); 
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  students   ",$con);
   while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $mark1=$rows['marks'];//what will do here
   $mark2=$rows['marks']; //should get value 55 and so on
}
```

Comment: each row has `50,55,67 .. etc` ?

Comment: `$array=explode(',',$rows['marks']);print_r($array)`

Comment: Obligatory [`mysql_` is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/de/migration55.deprecated.php) comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your values are comma separated then explode the field.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
include("db_connect.php"); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  students", $con);

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $mark=explode(',', $rows['marks']);//what will do here
   foreach($mark as $out) {
      echo $out;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Explode the data from the database. Use the [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

Access using indexes

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $marks = $row['marks']; //get value of marks from the database       
  $exp = explode("," , $marks); //explode marks data

  $mark1 = $exp[0]; //result is 50
  $mark2 = $exp[1]; //result is 55
  $mark3 = $exp[3]; //result is 67
}
```

Or loop using foreach

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $marks = $row['marks']; //get value of marks from the database
  $exp = explode("," , $marks); //explode marks data

  foreach($exp as $mark) {
    echo $mark;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If that row contains `,`, the just use `explode()`:

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $mark1 = explode(',', $rows['marks']); // should contain the comma separated values
    // in array form
    // then loop again
    foreach($mark1 as $mark_piece) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the explode function

```
$marks = explode(",", $rows['marks']);
foreach($marks as $mark){
  //your code to do something with the mark.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**N.B.**  `explode()` function breaks the string into array, it accepts three arguments,                                            first one is the delimiter that specifies where to break the string,                                                    second one is the string that needs splitting, and third one is not                                                 mandatory but it tells how many array to return.

```
$str_to_exploade = 'This,string,needs,some,exploiting';
$explode_string = explode(',', $str_to_exploade);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($explode_string);
echo $explode_string[0].'<br/>';
echo $explode_string[1];
```

More about explode() go to : http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php